# Solidity array has no SLOAD optimization

Tags: solidity, storage, compilation, compiler, optimization

Suppose a function writes to storage, and then reads from the same storage location before it has been overwritten. In solidity 0.8.11 in these cases the `SLOAD` gets optimized away (there is 1 `SSTORE` and 0 `SLOAD`):

```
uint256 private x;
function test() external returns (uint256) {
    x = 5;
    return x;
}
```

```
uint256[1] private x;
function test() external returns (uint256) {
    x[0] = 5;
    return x[0];
}
```

But in this (only a little bit more complex) case it does not (there is 1 `SSTORE` and 1 `SLOAD`):

```
uint256[1] private x;
function test(uint256 i) external returns (uint256) {
    x[i] = 5;
    return x[i];
}
```

With SLOAD cost having been increased from 200 to 800 it seems quite important.

In which cases is the `SLOAD` guaranteed to get optimized away?

Should we always manually optimize this?